# Parse.com Caching Compound Queries

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

Basic Parse.com queries are being cached but **I am unable to cache this specific query, I have ran this many time as suggested and cached results are always nil. Please advise a solution.**

```
PFQuery *lotsOfWins = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Class1"];
[lotsOfWins whereKey:@"Score" equalTo:@"0:]; //AND
[lotsOfWins whereKey:@"Status" notEqualTo:@"4"];

PFQuery *fewWins = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Class2"];
[fewWins whereKey:@"NAME" equalTo:@"KHAN"]; AND
[fewWins whereKey:@"meetingStatus" notEqualTo:@"4"];


PFQuery *query = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:fewWins,lotsOfWins,nil]];
[query orderByDescending:@"updatedAt"];
query.limit = [NSNumber numberWithInt:10];
query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork; // CACHE POLICY
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %d results.", results.count);
    if(error) {
        NSLog(@"It's an error!");
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Limit, is a NSInteger property, not a NSNumber. Tried query.limit = 10 and worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the query limit solved the problem. Apparently subqueries do not support limits.

> query.limit = [NSNumber numberWithInt:10]; //removed

Comment: This is not true. limit is an integer, not an NSNumber. query.limit = 10  should work just fine.